# how do I calculate a two-sided t.test for a data.frame where criteria for X and Y is specified in another column?

Tags: r

Let me explain using the built-in dataset mtcars

I want to compare the difference in MPG of cars with either automatic or manual transmission (known as 'am' in this dataset with auto being '0' and manual being '1'). You have one column with all the MPG data and another with the auto or manual data.

**My problem is, in this example, I don't know how to specify x being MPG datasets with manual, and Y being the MPG datasets with automatic.** So how do solve this problem? Thank you.

I have managed to solve the problem if I wanted to calcalte the mean for the above criteria using tapply. E.g:

```
mtcars = data.frame(mtcars)
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am, mean)

       0        1 
17.14737 24.39231
```

This is the logic I am trying to achive with the T.test.

Comment: Use the formula interface - `t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars)`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Thank you so much! You are a godsend.

Comment: @27ϕ9 if you don't mind, how would I make it so one t test use different error levels? conf.level = .9, .95, .99 didn't work